# Unittests for requests.post with no response

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-requests, pytest, python-unittest

I am wanting to write a unittest for a very simple function that has no response.

```
def post_this(url, data, headers):
    requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
```

Normally I would write unittests for something like this using the response = expected response. Or the 200 status code to show that the request was a success.

However, in this case neither of these are possible due to no response being given from the function.

I want to mock a unittest for the requests.post method - assert_called_once_with.
But I can't get this to work.

Any help I would be very grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: *What* is `post_this` supposed to do? (Calling `requests.post` only answers the question *how* it does that.)

Comment: Seems like it would almost be easier to just replace this function with direct calls to `requests.post` in your code base. The only thing it does is convert a pair of positional arguments to a pair of keyword arguments.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood the question, I suppose that the following code could be an answer to it:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch 
import requests

def post_this(url, data, headers):
    requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def test_post(self):
        with patch('requests.post') as mock_post:
            post_this('some_url', 'some_data', 'some_headers')
            mock_post.assert_called_once_with('some_url', json='some_data', headers='some_headers')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

As you can see in the code it is enough to use `patch` for `requests.post` and `assert_called_once_with()` (as you suggest in your question) on the mock object.